# Node js Stripe Received unknown parameter: dob

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, node-modules

according to the api here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=node#update_account

There is an object known as 'dob'

Yet when trying to run this code:

```
return stripe.accounts.update(
 stripeID,
 {
  dob: {
    day: day,
    month: month,
    year: year
  },

}
)
```

I get the error:

```
Received unknown parameter: dob
```

Is this the api or am I just using the api wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dob` is a child of `legal_entity`:

```
return stripe.accounts.update(
 stripeID,
 {
  legal_entity: {
    dob: {
      day: day,
      month: month,
      year: year
    }
  },

}
)
```